# Adding Values In A Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having a problem with my dictionary code. What i have so far is this-

```
def get_info():
    answer = "yes"
    d = {}
    while answer == "yes":
        a = input("Enter name: ")

        b = int(input("Enter hours: "))
        if b > 10 or b < 1:
            b = int(input("Enter hours: "))

        d[a] = b
        answer = yes_no("More Shifts?: ")

    if answer == "yes":
        get_info()
    elif answer == "no":    
        print(d)

def yes_no(msg):
    a = input(msg)
    while a!= "yes" and a!= "no":
        a = input("Enter yes or no: ")
    return a

def main():
    get_info()
```

it is working perfectly by adding all the inputs correctly to my dictionary but i can't seem to find a way to make it so that if i input, for example, "Andy" then "2" and then "Andy" and "2" again to make my dictionary at the end print out 'Andy': 4. Another reference example would be "Dan" 5 and "Dan" 3. My code will only print out the Dan 3 and not the total of the two. I hope i'm describing the issue clearly for anyone to understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MooingRawr that isn't technically correct: he's overwriting the value already stored for any specific key. he only creates the dictionary once, at the start of `get_info()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to check if the name is already in your dictionary, if so use `+=` instead of overwriting the first value.

```
if a in d:
    d[a] += b
else:
    d[a] = b
```

Comment: Python styling prefers an [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), rather than a look before you leap, methodology.

Answer (score 2):

You want to append new information if it doesn't already exist:

`d[a] = b`

should be

```
try:
    d[a] += b
except KeyError:
    d[a] = b
```

This follows the python styling preference that it is [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the previous value each time with your method.

What you need is `defaultdict` instead of standard dict, with default `int` type. Small example:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(int)

d["Dan"] += 2
d["Dan"] += 2
d["Andy"] = 10

print(d)
```

result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Dan': 4, 'Andy': 10})
```

in your context:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
while answer == "yes":
    ...
    d[a] += b
```